# SELinux context for a file both Apache and Tomcat can read/write to?

Tags: centos, redhat, selinux

What would be the correct context to use if we have Apache and Tomcat both installed on the system and need access to a particular file for read/write. Tomcat was installed using a source package and Tomcat user and group was manually created.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything that fits the requirement. You could make the file have a suitable tomcat based context and then use a local policy to grant httpd_t access or you could do it the other way round.